# Verbose syntax doesn't work in lightweight mode F#

Tags: f#

Microsoft F# manual says that [verbose syntax is always enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/verbose-syntax) in F#. If I understand that correctly, it means that F# code, written using verbose syntax, has to produce the same result whether lightweight syntax is enabled or not.

However, the code snippet below prints the number 6 ten times

```
#light "off"

let f x = for i = 1 to 10 do printfn "%d" x done in f 6
```

while the following generates the error: `Unexpected keyword 'in' in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.`

```
let f x = for i = 1 to 10 do printfn "%d" x done in f 6
```

What is the structural difference between these two snippets and why is the error generated when lightweight syntax is enabled?

Comment: Adding parentheses to explicitly show the scope of the `for` loop works: `let f x = (for i = 1 to 10 do printfn "%d" x done) in f 6` prints "6" ten times. I don't know the precise reason why the parser needs those parentheses in the default lightweight mode but not in verbose mode, though.

Comment: @rmunn yes, I've noticed that too and it makes me even more interested in why this actually happens. Is it not always possible to deduce the scope of the `for` loop when using `done` in lightweight mode? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

This verbose code:

```
#light "off"

let f x = for i = 1 to 10 do printfn "%d" x done in f 6
```

is equivalent to this lightweight code:

```
let f x = 
    for i = 1 to 10 do 
        printfn "%d" x 
f 6
```

in the lightweight mode the indentation defines the blocks, in verbose mode `do ... done` is the inner block of the `for` and `let ... in ...` is the block of the expression `f 6`.

Regarding why it complains when lightweight is on there are 2 possibilities:

- It could be a bug in the parser. Very few people use verbose and it may have gone unnoticed.
- It's also possible that both versions are no fully compatible. The documentation does say:

> even if you enable lightweight syntax, you can still use verbose
>   syntax for some constructs.

Notice how it says "some" and not "all".